# Coinjoin implementations

Tags: privacy, coinjoin

What are the different coinjoin implementations being used right now?

What are the trade-offs involved in using one of them?

Answer (score 2):

**Joinmarket**

> One group of participants (called market makers) will always be available to take part in CoinJoins at any time. Other participants (called market takers) can create a CoinJoin at any time. The takers pay a fee which incentivizes the makers. A form of smart contract is created, meaning the private keys will never be broadcasted outside of your computer, resulting in virtually zero risk of loss (aside from malware or bugs). As a result of free-market forces the fees will eventually be next to nothing.

https://github.com/JoinMarket-Org/joinmarket-clientserver

https://youtu.be/hwmvZVQ4C4M

**Wasabi**

Used [Zerolink](https://github.com/nopara73/ZeroLink) earlier.

> WabiSabi is a protocol for constructing CoinJoin transactions with the aid of a centralized coordinator. It utilizes keyed-verification anonymous credentials, homomorphic value commitments, and zero knowledge proofs to achieve privacy and flexibility.

> Coordinator will keep a registry of the separate inputs and outputs, ensuring that a user can only claim the amount of Bitcoin they are entitled to, but without learning about the links between these.

> WabiSabi builds on Chaumian Coin-
> Joins, adding support for arbitrarily variable amounts.

https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WabiSabi/releases/latest/download/WabiSabi.pdf

https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WabiSabi/blob/master/explainer.md

**Whirlpool**

> Whirlpool theory is based on a fork of the original ZeroLink framework which was originally co-written by nopara73 and TDevD, with thanks to Adam Gibson and Chris Belcher from JoinMarket, Ethan Heilman from TumbleBit, Dan Gershony from Breeze Wallet and Kristov Atlas from Open Bitcoin Privacy Project for their reviews, suggestions and feedback.

> Whirlpool is a fully modular CoinJoin implementation based on a heavily modified fork of the ZeroLink theory. You can review the theory or review the [architecture](https://code.samourai.io/whirlpool/Whirlpool/-/blob/whirlpool/ARCHITECTURE.md) in further detail.

https://code.samourai.io/whirlpool/Whirlpool

Opinion: Samourai and Whirlpool is a bad actor in this space, do not trust anyone on their marketing and tweets. Also if someone used research of other project and still pretends to be someone who invented something, blocks people with other opinion etc. is a **BIG RED FLAG** (Most probably proxy for government agencies)

*Nothing is "sufficient" for privacy. It's a goal to work towards, but it is so multi-faceted that no single piece of technology can "solve" privacy.*
 <sup>https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/e65vdf/could_bitcoins_privacy_benefit_from_litecoins_eb/f9oxfyk/</sup>

Comment: I don't agree on lot of things related to privacy and security with sipa even though he understands Bitcoin 1000x better than me however here I had to quote his reddit comment because I like it and agree with it. Hopefully its not seen as something I need to agree with him on everything.